# Flutter - BottomNavigationBar - SizedBox() Issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm new to flutter development.

I've been trying to add SizedBox() but I'm getting the following Error at compile time

The argument type 'SizedBox' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?'.

Parameter text[No errors were shown with SizedBox() then, but text parameter itself] was migrated to label as suggested by Flutter.

Here is my code which throws the error.

```html
BottomNavigationBarItem(
label: const SizedBox()
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `String` on `label`, It can be `label=""`

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
label: "Home"
),
```

More about [`BottomNavigationBarItem`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem-class.html)

Comment: I will encourage you to check this [doc example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

In this bottomBarItem label parameter you can't be assigning any widgets only assign String values if you want not to give any name you can assign them like this:

```
label : ""
```